# Finding the SUM of digits mapped to characters of a string

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 columns, one column with Alphabetic character and other column with value. Example 
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
E   5
Now I would like to get the sum of all digits corresponding to characters containing in a string. 
Like BAD = (2+1+4) = 7
Please suggest how this can be done in mysql (sql/procedure)

Comment: What have you tried so far?????  Have you even attempted something????

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

I used the following to setup the table with the characters and their numeric values:

```
-- create the table for char values.
CREATE TABLE charValues (
    charItem VARCHAR(1),
    charValue INT
);

-- insert the values to the table.
INSERT INTO charValues VALUES
    ('A', 1),
    ('B', 2),
    ('C', 3),
    ('D', 4),
    ('E', 5);
```

To get the count of each character on your value, you can use the following `FUNCTION` (in this case named `getCharCount`). This `FUNCTION` was created on the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001306/get-count-of-zeros-in-an-integer-using-mysql/42001521#42001521) and can be used in this case to get the count of each character:

```
-- function to count the count of a character.
CREATE FUNCTION getCharCount (colValue VARCHAR(255), searchValue CHAR(1)) 
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
RETURN (CHAR_LENGTH(colValue) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(colValue, searchValue, '')));
```

Now you can add a second `FUNCTION` to get the `SUM` of the value:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION getStrSum (colValue VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE retVal INT;
    SELECT SUM(getCharCount(colValue, charItem) * charValue) INTO retVal FROM charValues;
    RETURN retVal;
END //
```

Now you can use the following `SELECT` statement to get the calculated result based on table `charValues`. The functions can be used on the whole database like this:

```
SELECT getStrSum('BAD')  -- output: 7
SELECT getStrSum('DAD')  -- output: 9
```